# why is my Local Path mapping is a not a link in my Team Explorer Source Control window but my desk mates have there hyperlink

Tags: tfs

i have visual studio 2008 sp1 installed but still my team explorer dosent shows the hyper link of the local path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed Team Explorer after you installed VS SP1 then you need to re-run the SP1 installer in order to bring the Team Explorer bits up to date.

Answer (score 1):

This suggests that the install has either gone wrong or another update has interfered with your Visual Studio.

Can you try applying the service pack again?